# Is there any way to find average of song's amplitude?

Tags: software, sound

The question is a bit confusing, I know. Let me explain it. As you know song volume is represented by amplitude. When a singer sings loudly, the amplitude is high. For slow music, the amplitude is low.

I need to find the average amplitude of a song and a value for the average amplitude. According to these values I will try to decide what kind of music it is.

Does any one have any advice for me?

Comment: Volume is not represented by wavelength. Wavelength is exactly what is sounds like, the length of a sound wave, which is influenced by frequency, or pitch. If you are looking for a measure of the average volume, you are talking about amplitude; however, I doubt that an analysis consisting purely of amplitude would be able to tell you with any certainty what style of music it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tpburch Do you know any way to do the same thing for amplitude of songs??

Comment: Without looking it up, I'd guess that there would have to be software to find something like the root-mean-square of the waveform.  I don't think this tells you anything useful about the style, though, particularly since your analysis would be almost entirely dependent on how the recording was made, not on the style of the music.  You would have to have complete control over the recordings, not just the analysis.  Even then, I'm not sure how you plan to use the information to determine "what kind of music it is."  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to decide what kind of music, you will have to do an awful lot more than take an average of either amplitude or frequency.

Have a look at [this article on how Shazam works](http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/) - this identifies specific songs, but a subset of the analysis used in Shazam would be able to identify genres with some accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

To measure the average sound level over time, you would use an integrating-averaging sound meter. This will give you a decibel reading representing the average amplitude over the allotted period of time. Unfortunately, these can be quite expensive.

Comment: There's plenty of free software levelling plugins about; many are capable of doing long-time average RMS measurements.